# When will A and B meet?

Tags: least-common-multiple

There are two racers $A$ and $B$.

- speed of A: $1$ nodes/sec
- Speed of B: $2$ nodes/sec

Both of them race in a circular track as shown.

[image]

After how many seconds will the two racers meet again? How to derive a mathematical expression for the same?

I was trying using LCM but did not get a generalized expression for different speed and nodes.

Comment: What have you tried, dear nrb?  Please reread, and abide by, site expectations for askers  of questions.  You seem to not have learned or incorporated or exhibited those expectations, and I now write this on July 1, 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the number of seconds commenced. Then $A$ will be on the spot labeled $n \mod8$ and $B$ will be on the spit labeled $2n\mod8$. Then we want to find all values of $n$ such that $n\equiv 2n \mod 8$. This reduces to $7n\equiv0\mod8$. But $ \gcd(7,8)=1$ and therefore $n\equiv0\mod 8$, i.e. $n=8k$ for all natural numbers $k$.

Comment: When A completes one complete circuit, B will complete two complete circuits, so they will meet in 8 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed my definition of $n$. It's late lol

Comment: But n must not be an integer point. They can meet on an arbitraryposition between the points 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7-. Are you sure your calculation takes this into account?

Comment: @miracle173 I highly doubt that is what OP meant considering there is know notion of which direction they are moving or where they start. The OP also mentions the use of LCM which would infer a discrete interpretation.

Comment: The problem is clearly stated.  the OP apparently tried a wrong approach. To deduce anything from the (wrong) approach the OP uses is not tolerable. Either the OP stated the problem wrong or he misunderstood the problem. But to post a solution that ignores the problem stated is useless.

Comment: @miracle173 I'm gonna go ahead and say you're wrong and I'm right. My post answers OP's question. Also OP asked a question about modular arithmetic a couple days ago. If OP adjusts their post, I will delete my answer.

Comment: What the OP posted a couple of days before is of no relevance for this problem.

Comment: The only tag on the problem is least-common-multiple. Goodnight.

Comment: @AJStas where did 'This reduces to 7n≡0mod8' come from?

Comment: @nrb $n-2n=-n\mod 8$. And $-1\equiv 7\mod 8$.

Comment: @AJStas i am not familiar with simplifying eqn with mod operator :(

Comment: @nrb google modular arithmetic. It's basically like doing math on a clock.

Answer (score 0):

Consider it this way. Fold out the track for the first part of this problem so that it's a sort of "flat-world/Pac-Man" 1-D problem. Assign B's start position n nodes away and A's position at 0. So:

$$
\begin{eqnarray} x_A &=& v_A t& \pmod{n}\\
x_B& =& n-v_B t &\pmod{n}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

At the time they meet, the two values are equal. Setting the equations equal to each other and solving for the non-moded n term, we get

$$ n=(v_A+v_B)t\pmod{n}  $$

Now, while this is impossible to solve usually, it's a good thing we're on a circular track. n as a positional value here is equivalent to zero. Substituting 0 for n, you now have an equation that can be solved. This yields a time of 8 seconds for the particular scenario above.

Comment: Assign B's start position n nodes away and A's position at 0:Both of them start from same position

Comment: I'm aware of that. Which is why my solution unfolds the track into a line. Any time either runner moves off the track, they appear on the other side of it. With this in mind, runner B is n nodes to the left and we say for the first part of the argument that runner A is at zero just for the purpose of the setup. Once we get to the third equation I wrote, because of the fact that the end point and the start point are one in the same, the act of substituting "0" for "n" on the left hand side of the equation takes into account that runners A and B start from the same place.

Comment: @miracle173 : (Re: edit) You did indeed interpret it correctly, and thank you for the clean-up. My MathJax/LaTex is basic at best. I typically grab for what I need to try to make my equation at least understood.